# Self-teaching 1st year PhD Microeconomic Theory

Tags: microeconomics, self-study

How should one proceed if he wanted to master the microecon theory course typically taught in the 1st year of a PhD program on his own? Which text(s) and/or online course(s) should he follow? Suppose the guy has had a good training of econ up to the intermediate level and is familiar to the math topics the microecon course would typically demand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See graduate courses in microeconomics from http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/

Answer (score 7):

My prof is always telling us, if we want to pursue PhD level Econ in the future, we should master the full content of the following book:

Microeconomic Theory. Andreu Mas—Colell Michael D. Whinston and. Jerry R. Green. New York Oxford OXFORD UNIVERSITY PRESS 1995.

He also mentioned that there's main difference in viewpoint between graduate-level and top-level PhD Microeconomics. While in Grad School students calculate and theorize in the vector space, PhD students do mathematical operations using set theory almost all the time.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the PhD-level course itself? I was actually more eager to know about that.

Comment: We use Mas-Colell extensively. I would also recommend teaching yourself as much set theory as possible. Also, learn analysis and topology. That should be enough. Also, just use some Google-fu. Most good universities have full course notes and course outlines posted and available to the public.