# Best book to self-study microeconomics

Tags: microeconomics, self-study

What textbook(s) (and other resources) would you recommend to someone who wants to self-study microeconomics to an advanced (graduate) level starting from 0 (i.e. no formal background in economics)?

I have an undergraduate double major in a humanity and natural science. So there is a base of mathematical ability and knowledge of calc. I plan on improving in this area as well, so it isn't essential that all the requisite math is covered, but accessibility without a lack of rigor is of course preferred.

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/self-teaching-1st-year-phd-microeconomic-theory?rq=1) or [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39358/calculus-based-microeconomics-book?rq=1) question, do answers there answer your question? If not why?

Comment: Felix Muñoz-Garcia: advanced microeconomic theory (this comes with a book of solved practice questions) [advanced graduate level - but in a "friendly" way and with solved excercises if you buy the solution manual].

Comment: I would not recommend MWG - as the first and only - if you plan to self-study and have no background in economics. The book largely assumes that the student is familiar with basic intuitions and concepts of economic theory and rephrases these on more solid and abstract mathematical grounds. By all means read it but I think you will use your time more efficiently by not depending solely on that book given your description of your background.

Comment: There are a lot of [existing questions and answers on micro textbook recommendations](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=textbook+microeconomics).

Comment: @1muflon1 both those questions presuppose familiarity with economics and ask about expanding knowledge from and intermediate to an advanced level. I was wondering what the best book would be to go from virtually no economics background to an advanced understanding of microeconomics that would be expected during a PhD.

Comment: @asd7 actually no they do not, especially MWG starts from the first principles. I disagree with Jasper not recommending it. Yes MWG will have some jargon that you might not be familiar with it but if you pair MWG with any undergraduate textbook and just switch from MWG to undergrad textbook whenever you need a term to be explained you will do fine

Comment: @1muflon1 Thank you, in that case I will go with MWG since I have seen that recommended a lot and try supplementing it if/when I reach an impasse.

Comment: @asd7 as 1muflon1 says MWG starts from first principles but these are still presented in a fashion consistent with the goal of the book which is "to serve as a first year graduate book" - so the book are most certainly intended for readers previously exposed to economic theory. That is why I recommend you not to use it as your only source.

Comment: @1muflon1 I did not write I did not recommed it. I explicitly say that I would not recommed it as "as the first and only". That the book is meant "to serve as a first year graduate book" is the very first statement of MWG-Preface. There is no doubt that if you want to reach a graduate level MWG is a masterpiece.

Comment: I am in agreement with Jesper. I can't think of another subject matter where we would recommend a Ph.D. level text to someone wishing to learn the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

A good balance of intuition and rigour is given by a text called Chicago Price Theory and an accompanying YouTube series from Chicago Economics Dept.

https://home.uchicago.edu/cbm4/cpt/index.html

My only criticism of the YouTube series would be that the ordering of the videos is very poor. It would therefore require simultaneously consulting the text.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: No problem. Hope it is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Besanko](https://economics-pr.weebly.com/uploads/4/8/6/0/48608947/microeconomics-david_besanko_ronald_braeutigam-wiley____2013__zzz.pdf), because he provides a lot of examples and good practice problems. I have used this textbook and referred it to a lot of the people I tutor. Below is the 5th edition in pdf.

https://economics-pr.weebly.com/uploads/4/8/6/0/48608947/microeconomics-david_besanko_ronald_braeutigam-wiley____2013__zzz.pdf